# Can not connect datasource in Websphere docker: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DSRA8000E

Tags: docker, websphere

I run IBM Websphere container on docker and then config datasource to connect to oracle in admin console window, but I got the error:

> The test connection operation failed for data source ibanking on
>   server server1 at node DefaultNode01 with the following exception:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DSRA8000E: Java archive (JAR) or
>   compressed files do not exist in the path or the required access is
>   not allowed. Path: /home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar. View JVM logs for
>   further details.

I set the class path driver to lib, but not successfully: /home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar

Comment: Somewhere you have hardcoded path to the driver - `/home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar`. Are you using Liberty or traditional? How you are building your Docker image? How  did you set the path for the driver?

Comment: @Gas : I use traditional image on docker hub (https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker.websphere-traditional#docker-hub-image) . I tried to set JDBC to path "/home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original image doesn't contain any jdbc drivers, so you will need to include that in the image you are building. So in your dockerfile, you should have something similar to:

```
FROM ibmcom/websphere-traditional:latest
COPY --chown=was:was ojdbc6.jar /work/drivers
COPY --chown=was:was myApp.war /work/app
RUN /work/configure.sh
```

And then configure the jdbc path to the location that you placed the driver, as for me it seems that the `/home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar` is from your local file system, not from  the container itself.

Comment: Thank you, I was wrong when using the local file system as you said "the /home/quannt11/ojdbc6.jar is from your local file system, not from the container itself."